# grep gives only 'file xx matches'

Tags: grep

I try to find a certain error in a syslog with

```
grep panic /var/log/syslog
```

which works on several of my servers and shows the lines with `panic`, but not on one specific server (which is set up the same than the others). On this server I get only

```
Binary file /var/log/syslog matches
```

which is close to what I would get with the `-l` option. What can be wrong that I do not get the regular output, i.e. the lines which contain the word `panic`

Comment: Hint: Read the first word of grep's output.

Comment: thank you for the hint - forcing grep to take syslog as text file with the `--text` flag resolved the issue. I remain puzzled why syslog is considered a binary file on one of the servers but not on the others.

Answer (score 0):

The command which worked - as hinted by melpomene - was

```
grep panic /var/log/syslog --text
```

to force grep to consider syslog a textfile, not a binary file.